# Characterizing the set of positive integers which cannot be represented as $p+a^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

An exercise in Burton's book "Elementary Number Theory" 7ed, p43 prob 2, is to give a counterexample to the statement:

> Every positive integer $n$ has a representation $n=p+a^2$, where $p$ is $1$ or a prime, and $a\ge 0$ is a nonnegative integer.

This is false for $n=25$. I'm interested in finding all $n,$ or maybe some infinite families of $n$, for which it is false.

By looking at factors of a difference of squares, I found the family $n=m^2$, where $2m-1$ is composite. $25$ is in this family.

When $n$ is square the ability to factor makes the problem simple; so I'm looking for larger sets of counterexamples. I'd be surprised if one could characterize all $n$ which are counterexamples, but would want to use whatever result is found to actually generate the appropriate counterexamples.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A014090 and https://oeis.org/A020495.

Comment: Note this conjecture allows the use of 
p=1.

So it's not the same as finding positive integers not the sum of a prime and a square. That is, we count 
$n=1+
a^2$
as a representation, but the other way these don't count. –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No infinite family except squares is known. In fact, only $21$ numbers are known that are not a square nor a prime plus a square, see [OEIS/A020495](https://oeis.org/A020495):

$
10,34,58,85,91,130,214,226,370,526,706,730,771,1255,1351,1414,1906,2986,3676,9634,21679
$

Apparently, these are all the examples up to $3000000000$.

Comment: Note this conjecture allows the use of $p=1.$ So it's not the same as finding positive integers not the sum of a prime and a square. That is, we count $n=1+a^2$ as a representation, but the other way these don't count.

Comment: @coffeemath, by allowing $p=1$ we only reduce the list above, right? For instance, we remove $10, 226, 730$.

Comment: I realized the same thing (same removed numbers). So your reference settles my question,will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This set is [A014090](https://oeis.org/A014090), and related OEIS sequences:

- squares in this set: [A104275](https://oeis.org/A104275)^2
- nonsquares in this set: [A020495](https://oeis.org/A020495) (conjectured to be finite with 21 numbers, the largest number is 21679)
- 0 is not counted as square: [A064233](https://oeis.org/A064233)
- 0 is not counted as square, primes in this set: [A065377](https://oeis.org/A065377) (conjectured to be finite with 15 numbers, the largest number is 7549)

Related problem for the odd positive integers which cannot be represented as p+2*a^2 with prime p, this set is conjectured to be {1, 5777, 5993}

- 0 is not counted as square: [A060003](https://oeis.org/A060003) (conjectured to be finite with 10 numbers, the largest number is 5993)
- 0 is not counted as square, primes in this set (together with the “oddest” prime 2): [A042978](https://oeis.org/A042978) (conjectured to be finite with 8 numbers, the largest number is 1493)

The combine of these two problems: positive integers which cannot be represented as p+2*a^2 or 2*p+2*a^2 with odd prime p and 0 is not counted as square (i.e. p=2 or/and a=0 is not allowed), the set is 2*[A064233](https://oeis.org/A064233) together with [A060003](https://oeis.org/A060003) together the number 6 (6 is the only number requiring the even prime 2), and this set is infinite, since all 2*[A104275](https://oeis.org/A104275)^2 are in this set, and for all numbers in this set which are not twice a square number, see [A347567](https://oeis.org/A347567) ([A347567](https://oeis.org/A347567) = the union of 2*[A020495](https://oeis.org/A020495), 2*[A065377](https://oeis.org/A065377), [A060003](https://oeis.org/A060003), and the number 6 (6 is the only number requiring the even prime 2), thus [A347567](https://oeis.org/A347567) has 21 + 15 + 10 + 1 = 47 numbers), which is conjectured to be finite with 47 numbers, the largest number is 43358

And for the similar problem about triangular numbers (instead of square numbers):

This set is [A076768](https://oeis.org/A076768), and related OEIS sequences:

- triangular numbers in this set: 1+2+3+….+[A138666](https://oeis.org/A138666)
- non-triangular numbers in this set: (conjectured only the number 216)
- 0 is not counted as triangular number: [A111908](https://oeis.org/A111908)
- 0 is not counted as triangular number, non-triangular numbers in this set: [A255904](https://oeis.org/A255904)
- 0 is not counted as triangular number, primes in this set: [A065397](https://oeis.org/A065397) (conjectured to be finite with 4 numbers, the largest number is 211)

Related problem for the odd positive integers which cannot be represented as p+a*(a+1) with prime p, this set is conjectured to be {1}, and if 0 is not counted as triangular number, then this set is conjectured to be {1, 3}

The combine of these two problems: positive integers which cannot be represented as p+a*(a+1) or 2*p+a*(a+1) with odd prime p and 0 is not counted as triangular number (i.e. p=2 or/and a=0 is not allowed), the set is 2*[A111908](https://oeis.org/A111908) together with {1, 3} together the number 10 (10 is the only number requiring the even prime 2), and this set is infinite, since all 2*(1+2+3+….+[A138666](https://oeis.org/A138666)) are in this set, and for all numbers in this set which are not twice a triangular number, see [A347568](https://oeis.org/A347568) ([A347568](https://oeis.org/A347568) = the union of {432}, 2*[A065397](https://oeis.org/A065397), {1, 3}, and the number 10 (10 is the only number requiring the even prime 2), thus [A347568](https://oeis.org/A347568) has 1 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 8 numbers), which is conjectured to be finite with 8 numbers, the largest number is 432

Comment: A347567: {1, 3, 4, 6, 10, 17, 20, 26, 62, 68, 74, 116, 122, 137, 170, 182, 227, 254, 260, 428, 452, 740, 758, 878, 977, 1052, 1142, 1187, 1412, 1460, 1493, 1542, 1658, 1982, 2510, 2702, 2828, 3098, 3812, 5777, 5972, 5993, 6638, 7352, 15098, 19268, 43358}

Comment: Including: 2*A020495: {10, 34, 58, 85, 91, 130, 214, 226, 370, 526, 706, 730, 771, 1255, 1351, 1414, 1906, 2986, 3676, 9634, 21679}, 2*A065377: {2, 5, 13, 31, 37, 61, 127, 379, 439, 571, 829, 991, 1549, 3319, 7549}, the number 6 (the only number requiring the even prime 2), A060003: {1, 3, 17, 137, 227, 977, 1187, 1493, 5777, 5993}

Comment: A347568: {1, 3, 4, 10, 14, 122, 422, 432}

Comment: Including: 2*{216}, 2*A065397: {2, 7, 61, 211}, the number 10 (the only number requiring the even prime 2), {1, 3}